# Stanza implementation in XMPP

Tags: xmpp

I am developing a chat application based on XMPP/Jabber.  How the stanzas in XMPP are implemented in an application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll just have to use an XMPP library for the language you're developing it in. You could generate the stanzas yourself, but that would be re-inventing the wheel.

There's a fairly comprehensive list of libraries [here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/). For JavaScript I recommend [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/). For Java the best is [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) and for Android the best is [aSmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) (a port of Smack). The most comprehensive and up-to-date for Python is [SleekXMPP](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/wiki). The list goes on and on.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you too use any xmpp client libraries to implement because it helps you to code very faster, implementing the xmpp stanza's requires you to learn core of xmpp.

For all libraries you can visit [link](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/)

For PHP library you can use [JAXL](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/)